# Local variables Vs Global variable

Tags: c, initialization

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("the value is %d", a+'a');
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code `a` is local variable, And local variable are initialize to garbage value if we don't explicitly give them value . So the output should be some garbage value . But why am I getting output as `97`?

Comment: You're invoking undefined behaviour. There might very well be stored some random value in memory where you variable currently points to.

Comment: And 97 is a garbage value.

Comment: Who knows what information is stored at a's memory address? In this case, it's 97. Junk value.

Comment: 97 is actually a quite suspicious value, as it's the ASCII value for `a`. It could be that the compiler in this case, in a debug build, put the variable's name in there on purpose. Standardswise the value is of course undefined.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes more likely `a` happened to be `0`, and doing `'a' + 0` ends up with `'a'`

Comment: nice to see everyone is up to date with C11 :)  In C99 this was unspecified behaviour, if we are known to be on a system without trap representations.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes yeah i am confused here , that garbage value exactly matches with ASCII value .

Comment: @pritisharma who said `0` can't be a garbage value?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes The variable name should be stored for the debug build, and it's very likely the reason.

Comment: Yeah of course 0 can be a garbage value also .

Comment: Oh crap I missed the `+'a'` part, so it's just initialized to 0, either by accident or debugger. Will still be undefined on release build depending on the OS (`0xbaadfood` anyone?).

Answer (score 2):

In your code,

```
 printf("the value is %d", a+'a');
```

produces [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The output of UB, is, well, *undefined*.

You cannot rely upon (or justify) the outcome (*if any*) for a statement which invokes UB.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are stack variables. They are not initialized (unlike static variables). So better initialize yourself.

Comment: This should be a comment.